# change document filed data type in mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

How do I change the data type of a field from double to int32 for more the 10000 records in a document in mongodb compass.

Comment: You can write an aggregate query with [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) for field value conversion and then use `$out` stage.

Answer (score 4):

using compass GUI is not the solution, use shell or any driver, or even the integrated shell inside compass

`updateMany` can accept an aggregation pipeline, means allowing the update of a field based on its own value

simply use `$toInt`, [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/)

```
db.yourCollectionName.updateMany(
  {},
  [{ $set: { fieldName: { $toInt: "$fieldName" } } }]
)
```